# How can I buy a .by domain name

Tags: domain-registration

I can't find anywhere on the net to buy them.

Comment: Who did you end up using? This appears to be the official list: http://cctld.by/recorder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if they are the cheapest or most reliable: http://www.101domain.com/by.htm

Also, try http://www.google.com/search?q=buy+belarusian+domain

By the way (pun unintended), do ensure that you satisfy the registrant requirements. Some countries require that you have a physical presence in the country (residence, office etc) to register domains with their extension.